# What does kafka.server:type=KafkaServer,name=BrokerState with 4 mean?

Tags: apache-kafka

One broker shows `kafka.server:type=KafkaServer,name=BrokerState` mbean with the value of `4`.

[image]

I found [BrokerStates](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/BrokerStates.scala) that shows values for 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, and 7. What's `4`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State 4 means RunningAsController.
But it was removed 29 Jun 2016 by [this](https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/cf03f349caa92592ec42c7864b7f9d9ef21fee94) commit. And following message was added in docs:

> The BrokerState "RunningAsController" (value 4) has been removed. Due to a bug, a broker would only be in this state briefly before transitioning out of it and hence the impact of the removal should be minimal. The recommended way to detect if a given broker is the controller is via the kafka.controller:type=KafkaController,name=ActiveControllerCount metric.